# Multiple Realm clients showing new information but MongoDB showing old

Tags: realm

Extremely weird bug we’ve been facing today.

We have an iOS app which has updated a document using Realm SDK and I know it has been pushed successfully because I checked the `forCurrentlyOutstandingWork` session to confirm a 100% upload and also opened up another device to validate if it got the new updated information and it has.

The problem is even though Realm clients across multiple devices are showing the new updated information, the MongoDB doesn’t show the new updated information. It did update after 15 mins automatically but this issue happened to us multiple times today.

Has anybody else faced this issue and found a solution to it ? Or should this never happen and we need to report a bug ?

TIA

Edit:
Realm sync write log -

```
Logs:
[
  "Upload message contained 1 changeset(s)",
  "Integrating upload required conflict resolution to be performed on 0 of the changesets",
  "Latest server version is now 249"
]
Partition:

1
Write Summary:
{
  "Image": {
    "updated": [
      "612ce539db1dbb2655f6c723"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the data on the client is current, and matches data on other clients but the server is not showing the current data?

Comment: @Jay Yes. I triple confirmed it using multiple devices and in the Realm clients the data was updated but in the MongoDB it wasn't. Every time this issue happened today, it got fixed in 20 minutes on it's own in the MongoDB.

Comment: We have run into this before. Have you logged into the MongoDB Realm console and looked at the logs? The last time we had the issue, there were errors in the log - I don't recall the details, but it was an internal sync'ing error. So, check the logs and report back.

Comment: @Jay Added the log message from Realm to the original question. Says it requires a changeset but not sure what because I can't see any issues on the client logs.

Comment: If, when you are not seeing the current data in the console, if you stop sync and restart it, is the data refreshed correctly?

Comment: @Jay Yep I thought of that too. I paused the sync and restarted it but the updated item didn't show up immediately. It showed up after a while.

Comment: Aren't there more "interesting" logs? I'd be surprised if there were no errors. Sometimes isn't super easy to spot, but in Atlas/Logs you can filter by errors (in Status). It could be of help if you look into that.

Comment: At this point, since the issue is duplicatable and is server related, I don't think there's anything we can do to help here on SO. Please open a support ticket (using the chat to start with) in the Realm Console so their team can be made aware of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in MongoDB/Realm. I reached out to the support and they resolved it by pushing an update on the **9th of September 2021**.

Answer (score 0):

The replication to MongoDB is asynchronous due to the fact that conflict resolution must be performed against incoming writes from MongoDB clients (which sync does not control), to prevent the situation where a write made to MongoDB and a write made by a Realm client pass right by each other and leave the two states inconsistent. Ideally, these writes should happen within a few milliseconds but some latency can occasionally occur (especially around server restarts), but we closely monitor this and are always looking to optimize this.

- Engineer on the Sync Team